# Iterating over a single string with no spaces and identifying floats and ints in python

Tags: python, data-structures, stack, postfix-notation

I am trying to build an algorithm that converts infix to postfix. Here are the sample inputs below. You can see that it is all one string without spaces. Also, the inputs can have floats or integers as the operands. I'm trying to figure out how to go from left to right and identify whether or not an element is an operand(float or int).

```
theInput1 = "3.2+.4*5.67/6.145="
theInput2 = "11.897/3.4+9.2-0.4*6.9/12.6-16.7="
theInput3 = "234+34*65="
theInput4 = "(12+3)*(56/2)/(34-4)="
```

Someone here helped with regex:

```
import re
a = "11.897/3.4+9.2-0.4*6.9/12.6-16.7="
a2 = [x for x in re.split("(\d*\.?\d*)", a) if x != '']
print(a2)

s = []

for i in a2:
  if i >= '0' and i <= '9':
    s.append(i)

print(s)
```

Here's a2 after the regex:

```
['11.897', '/', '3.4', '+', '9.2', '-', '0.4', '*', '6.9', '/', '12.6', '-', '16.7', '=']
```

It looks like I got what I needed:

```
['11.897', '3.4', '0.4', '6.9', '12.6', '16.7']
```

Comment: You need to ask a more specific question than "any tips".  What code do you have so far and what problems do you have with it?

Comment: Quick question, are you trying to solve these inputs?

Comment: A regular expression could easily break these apart into groups of digits plus decimal points, and operators.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for something like this?

```
import re
theInput1 = "234+34*65="
theInput1 = re.split("(12+3)*(56/2)/(34-4)=",theInput1)
x = [char for char in theInput1 if char != '']
def typeOf(s):
    try:return int(s)
    except ValueError:return float(s)
for nums in x:
    y = typeOf(nums)
    print(type(y))
```